# printf command in bash

Tags: bash, printf

```
printf "%50s\n" " I ate 4 eggs"
```

In this example I want to assign 50 from a variable. And How can I use the variable in for loop in bash?

Any Idea?

Comment: Entirely unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am just trying fun, I do anything what comes on my mind.

Answer (score 6):

At least with `bash`, you can pass a variable field width using the C-style `printf` `*` conversion modifier:

```
width=50
printf '%*s\n' $width "I ate 4 eggs"
                                      I ate 4 eggs
```

See `man 3 printf` for details.

How to use it in a for loop will depend on what your desired output is.

---

Based on your comment, you could use

```
for i in {45..50}; do 
  for j in {1..13}; do 
    printf '%*.*s\n' $i $j "I ate 4 eggs"
  done
done
```

to supply both the field width and precision as variables, resulting in

```
                                   I
                                   I
                                  I a
                                 I at
                                I ate
                               I ate
                              I ate 4
                             I ate 4
                            I ate 4 e
                           I ate 4 eg
                          I ate 4 egg
                         I ate 4 eggs
                         I ate 4 eggs
                                     I
                                    I
                                   I a
                                  I at
                                 I ate
                                I ate
                               I ate 4
                              I ate 4
                             I ate 4 e
                            I ate 4 eg
                           I ate 4 egg
                          I ate 4 eggs
                          I ate 4 eggs
```

and so on.

Comment: for i in {45..50}; do for j in {1..13}; do printf "%${i}.${j}s\n" "I ate 4 eggs"; done; done

Comment: @barishatipoglu please remember to accept the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign 50 to a variable like so:

```
variable=50
```

You can use that variable in a for loop like so:

```
for i in foo bar baz; do
    printf "%${variable}s\n" "I ate 4 eggs"
done
```

---

In case you are trying to increment the padding on your printf statement you could do something like this:

```
$ for i in {45..50}; do printf "%${i}s\n" "I ate 4 eggs"; done
                                 I ate 4 eggs
                                  I ate 4 eggs
                                   I ate 4 eggs
                                    I ate 4 eggs
                                     I ate 4 eggs
                                      I ate 4 eggs
```